# Logging in then making a request in a thread-safe way

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, concurrency

I am using Java v1.7 and Spring Boot v1.3.3.RELEASE. I am trying to write a class that will hit a rest endpoint which requires authentication. So that I don't log in each time I wish to store the credentials between requests. If the session I am using has expired, I want to log back in and then try again.

Pseudo-code:

```
try
{
    getData(credentials);
}
catch (UnauthorizedException e)
{
    credentials = login(); // Multiple threads could get to this point
    getData(credentials);
}
```

However, this code is to be multi-threaded and I'm struggling to work out how I can guard against creating too many sessions.

Ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to ensure you don't loop forever if that exception is rethrown each time for another reason, but this should work:

```
for (;;) {
    Credentials local = credentials;
    try {
        getData(local);
        break;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedException e) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (credentials == local) {
                credentials = login();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only one thread should be able to call the login method. Other threads will wait at the synchronized block and then realize it has been updated by another thread and retry getData().

Comment: I need to tweak this slightly but this is a very good start. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to synchronize the access to the login method, so only one thread can access it and set the credentials. If another thread want to enter it must wait and then the credentials are set by the thread who already holded the lock.

Pseudo-Code:

```
try {
    getData(credentials);
} catch (UnauthorizedException e) {
    synchronize(lockObject) {
        if (credentials == null) {
            credentials = login();
            getData(credentials);
        }
    }
}
```

Outside of it you will have to set the credentials to null, to ensure that the if will work.

Comment: This won't work for several reasons. First, the credentials aren't null when they expire, second, if multiple threads enter the catch then they each try and login, third, everyone should get a second chance at getData. I'm thinking something with ReEntrantLock?

Comment: In my answer i just give a pseudo-code solution. The main answer ist to synchronize the access. If you do it with synchronized keyword or ReEntrantLock makes no matter.